# How can I populate other columns after user selects choice in drop-down?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that is essentially going to be a form for our user to print out and hand to the necessary individuals. What the user needs to be able to do is select a `customer number` from a drop down, choose his number, have 2 other (so a total of 3) columns populate.

I need the rest of the worksheet to stay in place. I have tried just about everything. How can I solve this with the simplest solution possible?

Comment: "i have tried just about everything." What have you tried? Have you accomplished any part of what you want? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: i have attempted VLOOKUP, advanced filters, and pivot tables...i was able to import the information i need to filter, now i need to figure out how to have only the 3 columns that are filtered change. the rest of the sheet needs to remain static so the user is able to fill in

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating a "Name" for the list of values and applying "Data Validation" over the field at which the user will be selecting the "customer number". You can refer [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-drop-down-list-HA102809802.aspx) which has details on how to create the same.

**Summary of how to do it**:

- Create a Named list (Formulas->Define Name, with the range selected):
  [image]
- On the field where you want drop down to be available, choose Data->Data Validation. And configure it to fetch values from the list you created
  [image]
- You'll now be able to pick one of the values from your list, using the drop down
  [image]

Edit:
Just realized answer to second part of the question (as to populating 2 other fields based on the drop down value selected) was not posted earlier.

To achieve this, you can maintain the look up value somewhere in the worksheet, with values from the drop down list and their corresponding values for the other two fields. Then simply use vlookup to populate the values,

**Sample**:

[image]

Formula used in cell "F2" is,

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A2:B3,2,FALSE)
```

**Note**: You can store the customer master lists in a different sheet and apply protection, so that no user changes it (accidentally or intentionally)